# Checking if option is selected under System Preference on Mac

Tags: terminal, mac, bash, script

I have an issue with  AD binding on Mac. Computer shows its already bind to AD but won't allow domain logins. What I noticed is "Allow network users to log in at login windows" option is grayed out. I have a script which allows me to rejoin AD remotely which is fine but I would like to know if there is a command or script that can go this setting and see if "Allow network...." is available and checked through terminal.

It would be great if someone can help me out or point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Fahed

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates that the domain record needs cleanup and not that the Mac is broken.

Have you removed the binding, cleared up the machine record (deleting it) and then re-adding the mac?

You could script the removal and binding or script the check in AD, but the language and script for each would be better asked as a follow on question if needed.